# How do I add a Bluetooth COM port in the Win8 Device Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, bluetooth

I am trying to set up terminal communication across two Windows 8.1 bluetooth devices - my workstation and an HP Stream 7 Tablet. The devices see each other, pair, and can transmit files, however the tablet's Bluetooth driver (RTL8723BS) does not have a COM port like the Workstation's does (BCM20702A0) and so I can't setup an outgoing port for a terminal. How do I set one up on the tablet side when it doesn't appear under Ports (COM & LPT) in the device manager? For comparison, here is the desktop:

[image]

and here is the tablet:

[image]

I've updated the tablet driver to its most recent and this feature still is not present. I've looked online for solutions and found only scuzzy sites.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the driver supports the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile, you’re out of luck.

However, in your screenshot, the “COM Ports” tab is available. If the COM port on your PC is properly exported and is paired, you can add an outgoing port there.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set everything up on the PC side because it complains that no serial service is running on the tablet.

Comment: No, of course. You need to set up one incoming port (advertised to paired devices) and an outgoing port on the other side. Maybe try redoing the pairing.

Comment: I get the same error, unfortunately: http://i.imgur.com/2OZpKBu.jpg

Comment: So did you check that your other system has, in fact, an incoming port configured? It has to be visible in the same dialog.

Comment: Yes, they both have an incoming port set up on COM3

Comment: Some info suggests you need to open the COM port on the “server”. Try opening the terminal emulator. If that doesn’t work, you need a program that explicitly acts as a SPP server.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of products that claim being able to create virtual COM ports over the network.
I have no experience with these products and suggest being careful when
installing them.

**HW VSP3 - Virtual Serial Port** (freeware, [website](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html))

> HW VSP is a software driver that adds a virtual serial port (e.g.
>   COM5) to the operating system and redirects the data from this port
>   via a TCP/IP network to another hardware interface, which is specified
>   by its IP address and port number.

**Free Virtual Serial Ports** (commercial)

Available from the [new website](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/virtual-serial-ports) and from the the [old website](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/virtual-serial-ports).
The difference between the two versions is unclear, but this feature is
quoted :

> HHD Software Virtual Serial Ports is a software package that allows
>   you to create virtual COM ports.
>
> Created virtual COM port may be used in ... Connected with remote
>   virtual COM port over network with flow control and baud rate
>   emulation.